# Multi step authentication & authorizatrion with JWT in SPA

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to understand how to handle tokens in a multi step authentication process for Single Page Application (SPA). This is what I am trying to achieve:

1. Ask user to enter username & password.
2. Ask user for one-time password.
3. Ask user to select company from list (a user can have access to multiple companies).

A user can have access to multiple companies, and user will have different permissions (claims) for different companies. So, assigning claims to user makes sense only when a company has been selected. So far I have implemented step 1 and step 2, without issuing any kind of token after password has been verified.

My question here is: after step 1 and step 2, do we issue some kind of (temporary) tokens?

Step 2): I assume that in order to enter OTP, we need some kind of proof that user was verified with a password. Otherwise, user can just directly navigate to OTP page, and bypass password login? Do I create a short lived token that contains Claim type: password, after successful password verification?

Step 3): And after successful enter of OTP I would issue a new short lived token, with Claim type: OTP?

And finally, when user selected Company, then I would issue short lived access token and long lived refresh token, to allow user prolonged session without the need to frequently authenticate?

If user decides to switch to another company, then just issue new short lived access token and refresh token for that company?

Can multiple refresh tokens exist for same website (one front end for multiple services), or will each new one cancel the old one?

I know there is an approach to use single token for all companies, but I am trying to keep token as small as possible, as recommended. Hypothetically speaking, if someone accessed 10 companies, and there are 100 different claims per each company, that would mean 1.000 claims to store in single JWT.